# Angular mention trigger when click any alphabet

Tags: angular, mention

In my angular project, I am using the angular-mention library for the suggestion of the usernames.
it is working fine if I type `@` or `#`. it will give me the user list only when I type @ or #.

But I don't want to type `@` or `#`. I want to type any alphabet so that it will give me the required result.
suppose if I typed j then it will give me all the username list which starts with character J or j.

can anyone help me with this?

you can refer to this [working code here...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyotig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link.

the above link is my working example available but it is working only when I typed @, I want to work when I typed any character

Also, I tried this as below

```
<input type="text" class="searchBox" [mention]="items" [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:''}" placeholder="Search user" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
```

in the above code triggerChar, I need to put some value if I put @ or # it will work according to that.
but to work for any character I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying the library. I assume this is stinky dirty hack that should not be recommended. But in case you really want it...

The `angular-mention` library uses `triggerChar` as key to index mention list.

```
// in file "angular-mentions/src/lib/mention.directive.ts"

let config = this.triggerChars[charPressed]; <= locate this line

/* custom code start */
const yourTriggerCharList = ['a', 'b', ...
if (yourTriggerCharList.indexOf(charPressed) >= 0 && !config && !this.searching) {
    config = this.triggerChars[anExistingTriggerChar];
}
/* custom code end */

if (config) { // <= triggerChar found
    ... (showing search list)
```

Comment: i also tried and found this is only way to use it without any triggerchar or blank trigger char.

Comment: There is an even dirtier way: duplicate search list with all possible trigger chars. I'm ashamed of myself coming up with this idea.